# Retrieving data with spaces from SQL

Tags: javascript, sql, google-maps

I'm trying to display custom icons on a map and I'm almost there, I just have a simple issue that I can't find an answer to. There are three types of icon which correspond to data in the database in a column called 'Scarcity'. I have the data in an xml file and the icons display for 'Common' and 'Rare' but don't display for 'Very rare'. How do I capture this data with spaces in js?

The js I'm using for the icons is:

```
var customIcons = {
     Common: {
     icon: '../Images/Common.png'},
     Rare: {
     icon: '../Images/Rare.png'},
     Very rare: {
     icon: '../Images/veryRare.png'}
 };
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will have to put keys in quotes like :

```
var customIcons = {
    'Common': {
        'icon': '../Images/Common.png'
    },
    'Rare': {
        'icon': '../Images/Rare.png'
    },
    'Very rare': {
        'icon': '../Images/veryRare.png'
    }
};
```

Comment: That's perfect thank you so much!